# Writing a script to bypass college login page

Tags: python, user-agent

My college has a silly login page that requires you to download a whole bunch of garbage that a lot of us don't need (Norton Anti-virus, Antispyware software, etc.).  We have to have them running to get on the internet on campus.  Though, if you are on Linux, or at least set your user-agent to linux, the requirements are gone.  We could easily use Firefox with the useragent switcher to bypass this, but it'd be nice to create a script that automates this.

How would this be possible?

I figure this could be written in python, and could grab the webpage with curl specifying a user agent?  How would I go about posting the data back to the servers?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, antivirus software is garbage.  Good plan.  Brilliant, even.

Comment: Strongly disagree with the closure of this question. "How do I send an HTTP request with custom user agent using libcurl" is the essential question here, and widely applicable.

Comment: Antivirus software isn't garbage, it's just that they require us to use this crappy Norton Anti-virus for college students

Comment: Seems like a good question to me, the college isn't named and the techniques would be generally applicable. I assume the correct answer isn't "go to a different college".

Comment: @gtredcvb, regardless of the fact that it might be utter rubbish that you need to install crappy software (which Norton is, I agree!), this is not the way to solve your problem. Go hold a petition within your college and give it to the people who can change this policy. Don't try to bypass it.

Comment: @user168715, sure, part of the question is fine, but I don't agree with it in its entire form (as do 4 other SO members it seems). Anyway, there could of course be 5 other forum members who'll vote to reopen: that's what SO is all about.

Comment: I don't understand why you'd want to do this with python... I *understand* having python try to talk to firefox/ie/chrome and switch the user agent (though this can have repercussions on what you see from different sites), but do you actually plan on having python fetch the page and then have firefox render it? ...a sort of proxy? 'cause if you issue one or two requests from python and then start browsing with your browser I'd **really** think you'll be blocked (unless they aren't that smart about their blocking)